# OSX Yosemite Finder sort by date modified wrong?

Tags: finder

In the image of an OSX Yosemite 10.10.2 Finder window below, you can see that the content of the 'blog' folder has been most recently modified. However, the 'Date modified' sort of the parent folder 'D' is not showing the 'blog' folder at the top of the list.

Why is this, and is there a way to sort the list as I intend? I seem to remember it was fine in previous versions of OSX.

[image]

Comment: In case anyone wants a quick way to update the date-modified, duplicating a child file/folder then deleting does the trick…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modification dates for folders are only updated when the folder's contents are edited, not the folder's contents' contents. In other words, you probably edited something in the DES folder, which changed the modification date for the DES folder, but you didn't create, remove, or edit anything directly inside the blog folder since 2015-01-06.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know if this behaviour has changed recently? It didn't seem to work this way before?!

Comment: @MachineElf: I just checked on Snow Leopard and it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you've mucked around with the custom date/time formatting in System Prefs, [as described here](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203413)?

Comment: That was an interesting link but no I didn't do any mucking about AFAIK :-)